# SugarCRM 'MyItem'

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am using sugarcrm 6.5 , there is checkbox in basic search, based on my understanding , when it is checked , it will search items assigned to my account. But how can I add these item to my account?

Comment: Presumably the answer is in here..
http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/?version=7.7&edition=Ultimate

Comment: "there is checkbox in basic search" is pretty vague. I'd imagine you're getting a lot of down-votes because the question is so poorly worded. I think what you mean to ask is how record ownership works in Sugar. If so, the answer that @Anirudha provided is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily manage record assignment in Sugar by changing the **Assigned User** field of the record. For multiple records, you can even perform Mass Update using following steps -

**Step1**
Go the list view of the module and select Mass Update option

[image]

**Step2**
After that change the **Assigned User** field

[image]